# Dotfuscator rise error: Value cannot be null

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, obfuscation, dotfuscator

i have problem with dotfuscator , then i set post-build event to dotfuscate my dll files i have receive 2 errors: Value cannot be null.  In my VSTO Project i have 5 projects for making .DLL files on outputs and then i set the post-build event by typing command:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\PreEmptive Solutions\Dotfuscator Professional Edition Evaluation 4.31.1\dotfuscator.exe" /in:$(TargetFileName)`

3 of 5 .dll are secessfully dotfuscating but 2 of them rises the same error. The error is :

```
    4>  [Build Output] Your subscription expires in 10 days. Visit https://www.preemptive.com/renewals to renew.
4>  [Build Output] Backed up existing renaming map file C:\Users\Andrejka\Documents\Dotfuscated\Map.xml to C:\Users\Andrejka\Documents\Dotfuscated\Map.7.xml
4>  [Build Output] Loading Assemblies...
4>  [Build Output] 
4>  [Build Output] Running C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\x64\ildasm.exe /OUT=C:\Users\Andrejka\AppData\Local\Temp\~Com.Vis.61\Com.VistaDraft.Lynx.dll.il /TEXT /NOBAR /RAWEH /QUOTEALLNAMES /UTF8 /FORWARD "C:\Users\Andrejka\Desktop\Projektas BW\walrus\Com.VistaDraft.Lynx\bin\Debug\Com.VistaDraft.Lynx.dll"

4>  [Build Output] 
4>  [Build Output] 
4>  [Build Output] Processing instrumentation attributes...
4>  [Build Output] 
4>  [Build Output] Analyzing Markup...
4>  [Build Output] Value cannot be null.
4>  Parameter name: key
4>  [Build Output] Build Error.
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5020,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\PreEmptive Solutions\Dotfuscator Professional Edition Evaluation 4.31.1\dotfuscator.exe" /in:Com.VistaDraft.Lynx.dll" exited with code 1.
```

Maybe whom know how i can solve this problem ? Please suggest !

Comment: I am a developer on the Dotfuscator team. It looks like you're using an evaluation of the paid Professional Edition, so you have access to our support team. You can [submit a support request here](https://www.preemptive.com/contact/supportrequestform).

Comment: @JoeSewell thanks for answer ! maybe you know how i can fix it without buy a license ? i need to know it because if all works well i buy it , but if is not for my project just leave it .

Comment: Your build output says you are using `Dotfuscator Professional Edition Evaluation 4.31.1`. During the evaluation period, you are allowed to submit a support request even if you haven't bought a license yet.